Grafana Dashboard with Loki to display a single number
Hi I have a Grafana Dashboard that I want to use to display the failed logs sent to Loki.
The logs look something like this
enter image description here
I have edited the query to show the sum of the number of error logs given on the interval and I have made a query like below
sum by (endpoint) (count_over_time({application="api-monitor"} |~ "status.*fail" [$__interval]))

enter image description here
I get a whole timeline even for the ones outside of the set intervals, when what I want is a single number that shows the total number of errors.
It would be deeply appreciated if you could tell me what is wrong and how I could fix my query to get the desired result.
Thank you in advance

Not $__interval, but $__range. And also in query options (under query) select type "Instant"

To get a single number showing the total errors within a specific time range, rather than a timeline, you can tweak your query a bit. Instead of using intervals, try to specify a fixed time range, like the last hour, day or week.
Here’s what I mean:
sum(count_over_time({application="api-monitor"} |~ "status.*fail" [1h]))

Here for instance, [1h] is the time range, so it counts all errors over the past hour.

Thanks this query and switching the data to stat got me the reult I wanted
